# Schwarzschild Radius of a Galaxy

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, event-horizon, galaxies

If an ultra compact/dense Galaxy has a Schwarzschild radius same as it is own radius, how can it be observed from the outside of the Galaxy?

Comment: Do you expect such things to exist? FWIW, one of the densest compact galaxies is [M60-UCD1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M60-UCD1), which has a mass around $1.4\times 10^8 M_\odot$, so its Schwarzschild radius is around 1380 light-seconds, but it's [half-light radius](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_radius) is around 80 light-years. Note that its nucleus is presumably a supermassive black hole with a mass around $2\times 10^7 M_\odot$. In comparison, the mass of M87* is around  $6.5\times 10^9 M_\odot$

Comment: That was actually the intention of the question. It is really difficult to know if there are any such galaxies due to the lack of ability to observe them

Answer (score 1):

If an ultra compact/dense Galaxy has a Schwarzschild radius same as it is own radius, it will have formed an event horizon around the galaxy. So, not only will the galaxy be unobservable for the rest of the galaxy, the inhibitants of said galaxy will be on an unavoidable trajectory towards collapse to a final singularity.

Comment: Outside observers could of course detect the existence of the galaxy through its gravitational interactions.

Answer (score 0):

Such Galaxy would probably look more like one single mass-body, no empty spaces left in between, would you still call it a galaxy? 
Gravitational effects as usual can be detected,so its presence would still be inferred indirectly. If you are speaking about detecting it through light, then light bending such as the lensing produced might provide you with indirect detection.

Answer (score 0):

> If an ultra compact/dense Galaxy has a Schwarzschild radius same as it is own radius

This is not possible. The Schwarzschild radius of a galaxy with say 200.000 solar masses is 590 km. Disregarding the fact that all stars would reach the singularity in very short time (for comparison 13 hours in case of 3 billion solar masses) the theoretical matter density inside the black hole would be much much higher than in case these stars are packed next to each other.

Comment: A black hole is formed after a gravitational collapse. This isn't possible for a galaxy regardless it's density. Apart from that see the density argument regarding the inside.

Comment: " it doesn't have to collapse." Reference please.